# Soap Fault Details custom exception

Tags: spring, web-services, exception, soap, jaxb

In the process of moving to Spring WS and using JAXB from wsdl to generate the objects used in the Soap message.  I am having an issue trying to get the Custom Exception into the details field of the Soap Fault message.  The following is how the existing fault message is returned (FooException embedded in detail).

```
<env:Envelope xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Service specific exception: com.test.FooException: Invalid authentication credentials. Please try again.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <n1:FooException xsi:type="n1:FooException" xmlns:n1="java:com.test">
               <errorCode xsi:type="xsd:int">101</errorCode>
               <errorReason xsi:type="xsd:string">InvalidUserCredentials:Invalid authentication credentials. Please try again</errorReason>
            </n1:FooException>
         </detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I have setup a customer exceptionResolver bean identifier in the spring config xml file.

```
   <bean id="exceptionResolver" class="com.test.FacadeExceptionHandler">
         <property name="order" value="1"></property>
         <property name="defaultFault" value="SERVER"/> 
         <property name="exceptionMappings"> 
             <value> com.test.FooException=SERVER,FaultMsg </value> 
         </property>
    </bean>
```

I created the FacadeExceptionHandler and it is getting called, but I cannot figure out how to get the FooException into the details portion of the fault message.

Any help would be appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Show us the implementation of `FooException`

Answer (score 0):

I think you almost get it all, in your `FacadeExceptionHandler` you must override the `customizeFault` method ([doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/server/endpoint/AbstractSoapFaultDefinitionExceptionResolver.html#customizeFault%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Exception,%20org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapFault%29)) and then add the detail for the fault (you have your Exception as a parameter there).

All this custom detail handling for Soap Fault messages is explained in detail in this entry: http://www.stevideter.com/2009/02/18/of-exceptionresolvers-and-xmlbeans/

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return to SOAP client fault with such depth of nested elements in `<detail>` element cause in Spring WS `SoapFault` has list of `SoapFaultDetail` which has list of `SoapFaultDetailElement` but `SoapFaultDetailElement` is just detail message in String. So in Spring WS max depth of SOAP Fault details is *one*.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Fault>
     <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Client</faultcode>
     <faultstring>Сообщение не соответствуют схеме сервиса СМЭВ.</faultstring>
     <detail>
        <InvalidContent xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/faults/1.1">cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'ns:SenderProvidedRequestData1'. One of '{"urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/1.1":SenderProvidedRequestData}' is expected.</InvalidContent>
        <InvalidContent xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/faults/1.1">cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'ns:CallerInformationSystemSignature' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.</InvalidContent>
        <InvalidContent xmlns="urn://x-artefacts-smev-gov-ru/services/message-exchange/types/faults/1.1">cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element 'ns:CallerInformationSystemSignature' is not complete. One of '{WC["http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"]}' is expected.</InvalidContent>
     </detail>
  </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
```